# NBAndroid not generating local.properties

Tags: android, netbeans

Im trying to work with android projects from multiple machines within NetBeans using the nbandroid plugin, but it doesnt seem to be generating the local.properties file automatically like its supposed to and I have to go in and manually change it each time to set the 'sdk.dir'.  It even says within the file that any changes will be overwritten.

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked in Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.

# location of the SDK. This is only used by Ant
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
sdk.dir=/Developer/android-sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be created if you open&close project customizer - 'android project update' will  be run on background. If it isn't then please file a bug http://kenai.com/jira/browse/NBANDROID

-Radim